# Different java client libraries for Google's PubSub and PubSub Lite needed?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I used the client lib for connecting PubSub so far:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now if I have to use PubSub Lite instead the question is if I have to switch to another client lib, like

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsublite</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Is that necessary or is there some compatibility?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar thanks for the answer, but this is only what can quickly be found with google... I would be more interested what I need to change in detail in my code. Certainly it is not done by just adding a second library...

Comment: Hi @micgn, can you provide the sample code?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar my code creates a topic as well as publishers and subscribers - just the normal PubSub business...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both  PubSub and PubSub Lite can be called using the Java Client library with few changes in dependencies. PubSub has a broader range of features then PubSub Lite but both are scalable and managed messaging services.
The difference while using PubSub and PubSub Lite is that while using PubSub Lite you need to add both PubSub and PubSub Lite artifacts in dependency in the pom.xml file which is mentioned below.

**PubSub**

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
      <version>26.1.5</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
 
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
  </dependency>
 
</dependencies>
```

**PubSub Lite**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsublite</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
  <version>1.122.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For more information you can check the Java Client Library for [PubSub](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub) and [PubSub Lite](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsublite).